# How to custom map property to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

Desired JSON:

```
"MyRootAttr": {
    "value": "My Value"
}
```

Property definition in the class:

```
public string MyRootAttr { get; set; }
```

So, the question is, without defining a new class, with a single string property, how can i achieve the JSON I want?

Comment: Maybe an anonymous type would help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to alter your class structure, you can use a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to achieve the result you want:

```
class WrappedStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject(new JProperty("value", s));
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        return (string)jo["value"];
    }
}
```

To use it, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your string property like this:

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(WrappedStringConverter))]
    public string MyRootAttr { get; set; }
}
```

Round-trip demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y1y5vb

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) could help accomplish this:

```
var myObj = new { MyRootAttr = new { value = "My Value" } };
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(myObj); //{"MyRootAttr":{"value":"My Value"}}
```

With Json.net:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj); //{"MyRootAttr":{"value":"My Value"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple string formatting or build the json string manually.

```
var str = String.Format("\"MyRootAttr\": {{ \"value\": \"{{0}}\" }}", MyRootAttr);
```

Comment: var str = String.Format("\"MyRootAttr\": {{ \"value\": \"{{0}}\" }}", MyRootAttr);