# Map enum to json property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class called InstrumentConfigValues with properties that has type implementing an interface. Now I have an enum by name InstrumentConfig which has set of values. These values are like keys inside the json file. I want to map something like `[JsonProperty(InstrumentConfig.LowDiskpace.ToString()]`.

For some reason its not allowing this and complains saying:

> An attribute argument must be constant expression

I referred to many post specifically [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/). But how can I map each property with the enum key. I also saw this post [JsonSerializationSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418649/how-to-custom-map-property-to-json) but not able to correlate to my problem. Please help/

```
public class InstrumentConfigValues : IInstrumentConfig
{      
    public double SpaceNeededForSingleRun
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int NumberOfInputSlots
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int SupportedChannelCount
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

//I want this inheritance as some other class wants to access the values.
public abstract class InstrumentConfigReadWrite : InstrumentConfigValues
{
    protected ReturnCodes PopulateValuesFromJObject(JObject jObject, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstrumentConfigValues>(jObject.ToString()) == null)
            {
                return ReturnCodes.ErrorReadingFile;
            }
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException jex)
        {
            SystemDebugLogLogger.LogException(jex, "Invalid Instrument Config File Values. Data needs to be copied over.");
            return ReturnCodes.ErrorReadingFile;
        }
        return ReturnCodes.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `[JsonProperty(InstrumentConfig.LowDiskpace.ToString()]` to do? If this did work, the property _name_ would become `LowDiskpace` (disk pace?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/net-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ...- Create an attribute of type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859094/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-create-an-attribute-of)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to serialize instances of `InstrumentConfigValues` as a simple string, right?  If so, see [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40480742/3744182).  If not, could you please clarify your question with a [mcve] showing example(s) of your models and the JSON you want to generate?

Comment: In my situation I want to ensure that the keys in the json file maps to the names in the enum. Eg: in my enum if I have lowdiskspace And in my json I have lowdiskspace:25, then the keys both match. Otherwise if it's something like lowdisksp:25 then  I want to say it's an invalid json file because the keys mismatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're using a current compiler, you can use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).

```cs
[JsonProperty(nameof(InstrumentConfig.LowDiskpace))]
```

If you try using this, and get an error like `Compilation error: The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context`, that means you're not using a current compiler. The `nameof` keyword was introduced in C# 6.0/Visual Studio 2015--anything newer than that should be fine.